NO_PUBKEY 24A1004B1F11DCC9
Yes this has been asked before and I have tried every solution I have found. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and browser is Opera 87.0.4390.45 I am trying to upgrade both os and browser however the no-pubkey error is preventing this. Also under the tab "Authentication" in software and updates, It indicates the key does exist in my system.
If I deselect the offending repositories in the Other Software list, would this be a bad thing if it allows me to up grade? I have yet to try, but I am getting frustrated with solutions that are not working.

No it is not a bad idea, but whu upgrade?Since 20.04 will go out of support and since you have to backup before upgrading, Why not take your time, do the backup necessary, look in your setting see what you have changed and run the USB with "Try Ubuntu" and check all your hardware and at last install 24.04, If the system is not robust enough you can take a look at Ubuntu Flavors.

Ubuntu 18.04 went EOL on May 31, 2023 and is not supported on this site sorry.

This question is similar to: How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

I politely disagree with the close votes. This does not seem a question about maintaining an EOL system, nor about fixing the pubkey error. This seems a question about safely release-upgrading to a supported release of Ubuntu, which is an on-topic question.

The OPs question mentions upgrade without giving specific details; thus I read the upgrade as being upgrade of packages on an unsupported or EOSS release, rather than a release-upgrade process.  @user535733

Best practice is to:

Deselect the offending repositories
AND
Uninstall the software from those repositories.

Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible for the greatest likelihood of success.
After your release-upgrade has succeeded, you can reinstall the non-Ubuntu add-ons.

Thank You for actually reading my post.
